# Proper way to tap into two cables terminated at ceiling j box and add light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to add a single pole light switch that powers a ceiling light. Currently, there is no switch but there is a ceiling j box with two 14/2 Romex cables connected together. Black to black, white to white, etc.

My thought is to switch the hot line going to the light by inserting the switch.

So take white from the switch and tap into black wires at box.

Then take the black from switch and tap into black at the light.

Then ground to box and light fixture.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

What you are speaking of is a switch loop that is no longer allowed by NEC. Because the switch box would not have a neutral. Your description assumes that all the wires are on a single circuit and the 14/3 wiring has a ground and 3 leads, ( black red and white).
To add the switch correctly use 14/3 to the switch. Black and red on the switch and ground to the ground lug. The neutral is capped and left in the box for future use if a Smart switch or other device is used that requires a neutral.
At the J-box the hot to the light is disconnected and now tied to the black to the switch. The red from the switch is connected to the hot line to the light ( should be black). The white neutrals are all tied together as are the grounds. Of course turn off power first to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was probably done a while back with the original box. I adapted number three from this website for the concept as I’ve done this before with fans. so it sounds like it’s not up to code anymore but is what I proposed safe? I tested it just now as I was doing some other work. I’m confused what you mean by switch box not having a neutral. Neutral is there connected to light. #3 in this somewhat but no fan, just a light: https://www.protoolreviews.com/wiring-connecting-ceiling-fan/

Comment: Also the existing wiring is 14/2 terminated together not 14/3. That was a typo. Do you have a link to a diagram by chance?

Comment: Neutral always has to be at the light. In the old days, neutral did *not* have to be at the switch. Current code requires neutral at the switch in order to provide power, if needed, for timer/smart switch/motion sensor/etc. which are all much more common than they used to be.

Comment: @ Dalk, Yes #3 in protoolreviews is the old way of doing a switch loop that was considered safe "back in the day"  Now it is not code because of the lack of neutral in the box housing the switch as explained above.